# Not able to access list of record in EF

Tags: entity-framework

Here is the problem I am trying to access some records from the data base based on  one  field . The field I am using is audit_id having type GUID .

but the line does not returning any data

```
var audits = ctx.Audits.Where(x => lstAudits.Contains(x.audit_id)).ToList();
```

Here is a my full code to update mass records in the database using EF

```
//will select auditId from the List
        var lstAudits = _ViewModel.WorkingListAudits.Where(x => x.WorkingList).Select(x=>x.AuditId).ToList();            
        using (var ctx = new AuditEntities())
        {
            var audits = ctx.Audits.Where(x => lstAudits.Contains(x.audit_id)).ToList();
            audits.ForEach(x => x.working_list = false);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
```

In case of single record it return data from database

```
  var lstAudits = _ViewModel.WorkingListAudits.Where(x => x.WorkingList).Select(x => x.AuditId).ToList();
        Guid tempAuditId = lstAudits[0];
        // lstAudits.ForEach(x => x.ToString().ToUpper());
        using (var ctx = new AuditEntities())
        {
            var audits = (from au in ctx.Audits
                          where au.audit_id == tempAuditId
                          select au).ToList();
            //foreach(Audit audit in   audits){

            //}
            audits[0].working_list = false;
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Finally I got the answer here is the updated code which is working fine .I just took some intermediate result in a temporary variable and it started working as expected

```
  //will select auditId from the List
           var lstAudits = _ViewModel.WorkingListAudits.Where(x => x.WorkingList).Select(x => x.AuditId).ToList();
        using (var ctx = new AuditEntities())
        {
            var tempAudits = ctx.Audits.ToList();
            var audits = tempAudits.Where(x => lstAudits.Contains(x.audit_id)).ToList();
            audits.ForEach(x => x.working_list = false);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Comment: But `ctx.Audits.ToList()` returns something, right? (just to check if the table isn't empty and the connection string doesn't point to the wrong DB)

Comment: ctx.Audits.ToList() is not returning any data .Connection string is fine and  it pointing to the right DB .

Comment: ctx.Audits.ToList() returning 0 no. of records .But there are some data in the DB corresponding to those id in list lstAudits .

Comment: But if `ctx.Audits.List()` returns nothing the problem is not in the `Where` clause nor the guid list but somewhere else. Connection string is really the most likely reason. Do you have the connection string in the correct project (common mistake is to have it in a library project instead of the main executable project)? Can you load any data at all from any other table?

Comment: Yes I am able to load data from the other table .In case of single records it working fine see my updated post.But in case of multiple records it's not working fine .  I dont want to get single record but I want to get all records having id's 
in lstAudits .

Comment: Finally I got the answer I have put the updated code which is working fine .I just took some intermediate result in a temporary variable and then I performed searchin things on the temporary variable and got the expected result .It's really strange but it's working .

Comment: But you said that `ctx.Audits.ToList()` is "*not returning any data*".  How can your solution work then??? Anyway, your solution can turn out to be terrible slow and memory wasting over time when the `Audits` table grows because you load the whole table into memory.

Comment: Do you have any Idea why var audits = ctx.Audits.Where(x => lstAudits.Contains(x.audit_id)).ToList(); not returning data But 
 var tempAudits = ctx.Audits.ToList();
            var audits = tempAudits.Where(x => lstAudits.Contains(x.audit_id)).ToList();  line returning data .